# Android application running only in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to run an android application. The problem is the application gets terminated when choose "run" the app from my IDE. But when I try debugging, it is working fine. App works perfectly fine when I debug. I tried both intellij and eclipse, but same issue. I tried creating signed apk and run, but same issue. How can i resolve this problem.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the crash when it terminates? Sounds like it might be a concurrency issue.

Comment: the app is not crashing. its just running in debug mode. otherwise, its just closing. no errors nothing. or sometimes if there is a progress dialog, it never get dismissed.